# Control my smart home devices when I enter room with my Nest Hub Max

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home, google-smart-home

I have a nest hub max which is located in one my rooms. Is it possible for me to trigger an action when it detects I have entered the room?
I know that the Nest hub Max can detect if I am nearby or when I am in the room. So far I have only found local actions on goole however those are still google assistant actions with voice commands.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism to use presence or entering a room as a trigger for a routine or series of actions.